# How to return HTMLDivElement to Java code

Tags: javascript, java, dom

In Java project I use `Browser` to show page. I used JavaScript and mapped Java method to get element from document.

My JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById(`actionButton`);

if(element != null)
   buttonFound(element);
```

`button` is a `DivHtmlElement`.

Mapped Java method `buttonFound`

```
ButtonFoundFunction(this, browser, "buttonFound");
```

... which extends `BrowserFunction` and overrided method

```
@Override
public Object function(Object[] arguments) {
    browser.execute(arguments[0] + ".click()");
}
```

But method `function` is not called(?).

I tried return not `DivHtmlElement` but simple button id as below JavaScript shows:

```
buttonFound(`actionButton`);
```

and then on overrided `function` call to click

```
@Override
public Object function(Object[] arguments) {
    browser.execute("document.getElementById('" + arguments[0] + "').click();");
}
```

... and it works but it search button by id two times, first in JavaScript, second when call `function`.

How to return `DivHtmlElement` to this `function` ?

**EDIT**

The first JavaScript which search the button:

```
var buttons = [];

var buttons[0] = document.getElementById(`actionButton`);
```

The second JavaScript which only execute click on index:

```
function doClick(index){
   buttons[index].click();     
}
```

Comment: what is a `DivHtmlElement`? do you mean [`Javascript's HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)? you can't pass a native JS object to another language..

Comment: Is this SWT's `Browser` class? If so, the execute method can only evaluate JavaScript in the context of the browser, you can't access the DOM elements directly.

Comment: `DivHtmlElement` is a part of `DOM`. The `browser` is class of SWT's `Browser`. So maybe there is other option to do click on DOM element ? Maybe execute second JavaScript in this `Browser` object and the `DivHtmlElement` is held in cache ? And then second JS (which only call click) take value from cached array and click ?

Comment: @SeanBright edited my question and write example JavaScripts. This is possible in the same SWT `Browser` object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@I wrestled a bear once` says that I can't pass a native JS object to Java, so I did the same thing differently.

When JavaScript looks like that:

```
var buttons = [];

var buttons[0] = document.getElementById(`actionButton`);
```

to execute click in Java it is enough by code:

```
browser.execute("buttons[0].click()");
```

Because `buttons` array is in SWT `Browser` cache.